# The simpliest way to visualize - easy-use graphics. Which languages and lib?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, visualization

I'm going to develop math model of trafics simulation and will need to somehow vizualise it. The model will be in C++

I'd like someone to recommend me how can I  visualise the result data file - e.g. paint cars, road etc. Language choose is not important but should be easy enough to  go into.

os: Win32

UPD:
It'd better be the 2D not 3D
but actually - doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best quality and most general software I've seen is Graphviz.

http://www.graphviz.org/

Comment: graphviz is awesome for rendering graphs - not sure it would do what is being asked for here though.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard lots of good things about [`VTK`](http://www.vtk.org/) (not yet had the occasion to use it myself).

The Wiki contains lots of [C++ examples](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx).

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not know how (or even if) it interfaces with C++ you may be interested in [processing](http://www.processing.org) to quickly build visualizations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more 2D than 3D and if you know C++, then using Qt and notably its [Qt Graphics View framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview.html) could be ok.